# missing steps in my jest configuration after npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

Following documentation I added jest. This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "sensorario",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "7.43.5",
    "react-query": "3.39.3",
    "react-router-dom": "6.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.18.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "14.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "29.5.0",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

here my `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }],
    ],
};
```

and `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    "testMatch": ["**/__test__/**"]
}
```

and `__test__/App.test.js` file

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from '../src/App'

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

and running `npm test` the result is

```
npm test | pbcopy                                                                                                        git:master*
npm● Multiple configurations found:
    * /Users/simonegentili/Development/github.com/sensorario/youtube.react/jest.config.js
    * `jest` key in /Users/simonegentili/Development/github.com/sensorario/youtube.react/package.json

  Implicit config resolution does not allow multiple configuration files.
  Either remove unused config files or select one explicitly with `--config`.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html

FAIL __test__/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/simonegentili/Development/github.com/sensorario/youtube.react/src/App.css:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){.App {
                                                                                      ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

    > 1 | import './App.css';
        | ^
      2 | import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
      3 |
      4 | function App() {

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.js:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.118 s
Ran all test suites.
youtube.react ➤                                                                                                                          git:master*
```

I've followed more and more documentations. From React one to Jest. What is the flow of configurations of babel and jest? Is it possible that jsx code is not compiled and test cant run with non transpiled code?